# Merge/synonymize [text-formatting], [textformatting], and [textformat]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

These three tags, [text-formatting](/questions/tagged/text-formatting), [textformatting](/questions/tagged/textformatting), and [textformat](/questions/tagged/textformat), are the same thing, yet the tags link to three different sets of questions. Can these be merged and/or be given a synonym relationship?

Comment: Wouldn't "text formatting" be a meta tag to begin with?  The meaning is subjective and I can't see it standing alone...

Comment: @Charles I think you have a point for some cases, but not sure if it's *never* ok to stand on its own.